# Any way to use —arguments on aws glue start-job-run to append

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli, aws-glue

From the AWS documentation, it looks like we can use —-arguments to start-job-run to replace default arguments. Are there any way to append to existing arguments rather than replacing the entire list?

Comment: Have you tried just passing them with —-arguments ? If they are of different names then they should just get appended to the existing arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, only the provided arguments are replaced and not the entire default arguments map.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html) is the list of arguments you can provide and the default value for each not present one.